# GET ChallengeQuestion API in version 6.0 is not working

Tags: wso2-identity-server

As part of WSO2 identity server 6.0.0, SOAP APIs are deprecated and recommended to use REST-based APIs. We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs in our project, want to replace the SOAP APIs with recommended REST APIs. Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs to replace RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs. The APIs document is not clear.

Under Challenge Questions API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/apis/restapis/challenge.yaml we are calling /me/challenges and /me/challenge-answers GET APIs and we are getting response as No message body writer has been found for class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType: / , 500 Internal error. Can you please suggest what is going wrong here what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 'Accept: application/json' header in the REST API request.

Try the following sample curl commands by changing the Authorization header value

/me/challenges:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost:9443/api/users/v1/me/challenges' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded username:password>'
```

me/challenge-answers:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost:9443/api/users/v1/me/challenge-answers' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded username:password>'
```